# Accessing a variable defined on one script from a function in another script in Python

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, global

I have 3 python scripts. In my first python script named first.py I have a function called missing_days_check() (Here i have to access the flow_rate from third script which will be executed later)

```
def missing_days_check() :
    ........
    date = today
    df = flow_rate.copy()
```

In my second script called second.py (Here also I have to access the variable flow_rate from third script which will be executed later)

```
from first import *
def checks() :
    ......
    days = missing_days_check()
    df_new = flow_rate.copy()
```

In my third script named third.py

```
from second import *
flow_rate = pd.read_csv('/data/flow_rate.csv')
check = checks()
................
```

When I run the script from first to third I get library dependency errors.
I want to create functions in first two scripts and the variable flow_rate in those functions should be accessed from third script. How to do that?

Comment: Looks like you have a dependency cycle. If you draw the dependencies on a piece of paper to show which files require others, you need to make sure that is acyclic. Move `flow_rate` into a file on it's own that does not reference `first.py` or `second.py`.

Comment: But the issue is that the dataframe flow_rate is not a fixed one and it will be updated in a loop. so how to overcome this?

Comment: I'm still a little unclear on what you want to achieve. Please provide a sample output and your expected code.Then we can maybe help you change the structure of your code accordingly.